# TableModelListener only works sometimes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have a database application that uses a jTable (using netbeans), I have added a table model listener to the jTable so when I edit the jTable it also edits the database (MySQL).  It works however when the user clicks off the jTable and clicks a button it stops working.

**Edit:** Ive realised that it only stops working when I run         "jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(mySql.UpdateTable()));" to update the table.  When I press a button that runs this line it stops working, any other button or any other time and it works.

to update table:

```
    public ResultSet UpdateTable(){

        Connection con = connect();
    try{
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset;
        resultset =  s.executeQuery("select * from customera");
        return resultset;
        }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

tablemodellistener class:

```
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;

public class TableActionListener implements TableModelListener{

Rob1 r;

public TableActionListener(){
    r = new Rob1();
    }

public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
    System.out.println("action");
    int id = r.getID();
    int column = e.getColumn();
    int row = e.getFirstRow();



    }

}
```

added table model listener like so in constructor:

```
jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener( new TableActionListener());
```

to get the row clicked i've added this code:

```
int id;

private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println(evt.getClickCount());

        int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        int col = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
        id = (int)jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);

}
```

to return current id:

```
 public int getID(){
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve and how is it failing?

Comment: After setModel, the listener listens on the obsolete model, one needs to add the listener to the new model. Could that be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "set model" ?

Answer (score 1):

> It works however when the user clicks off the jTable and clicks a button it stops working.

By default the table cell editor is only stopped editing when you move to another cell in the table.

So when you click on another component you need to tell the table to stop editing. Then the data will be saved and the TableModelListener will be invoked.

Check out [Table Stop Editing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for two ways to do this:

1) Add a property to the table:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

2) Add code to the listener of your button:

```
if (table.isEditing())
     table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```

You may also want to check out [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) which may be more appropriate to use instead of the TableModelListener.

Comment: I tried this but have the same problem, I've edited my original post to show what I have found out.